# ! Extra \right error when using Bmatrix command

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices

I have a strange message when I try to compile my document when I use the `Bmatrix` command, compiling this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,english,italian]{book}% twoside!
\usepackage[twoside=true]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
  margin=3cm,
  top=3.8cm,
 bindingoffset=0.4cm
}

\usepackage{phdthesis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bnf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{phdtitle}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{bibentry}
%\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,pdftex=false,bookmarksopen=true,pdfborder={0,0,0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}%[per-mode = symbol]
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}

\hyphenation{}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]
\lstset{tabsize=2,basicstyle=\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
\usepackage[greek,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont


\begin{equation}
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 2\\ 3 \\ 4\\ 5
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

I reported only the part of my document causing this error, without this equation the document is compiled correctly. I don't understand the error since I have copied the `Bmatrix` from the `amsmath` documentation.

This is the error I get:

```
! Extra \right. \rbrace ->\delimiter "5267309 l.325 \end{Bmatrix}
I'm ignoring a \right that had no matching \left.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.325 \end{Bmatrix}


! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.325 \end{Bmatrix}


! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno
\alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.326 \end{equation}


! Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text>
\right .
l.326 \end{equation}


! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
l.326 \end{equation}
```

Is there any package conflicting with `amsmath`? I can't figure out why I get this error, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The package `mdwtab` rewrites the base LaTeX `tabular`/`array` environment. Try loading this *after*  all tabular-related packages.

Comment: Don't load `mdwtab`: it's old, unmaintained and conflicts with other packages.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked

Comment: are you sure you want this `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` ? Most systems should be using UTF-8 these days.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the `xcolor` an `colortbl` packages independently. To maximize their interoperability, write `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.